# Method is available in sandbox but not in prod

Tags: apex, deployment, cli

I've composed an apex classes in sanbox, test classes as well. It works fine in sandbox. Now i wanna deploy to prod without using changesets and packages.

***a part of apex***

```
@testVisible
   protected RestClient() {
   }
```

***a part of test class***

```
test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new HistoryMock());
    RestClient dummy = new RestClient();
```

my manual deployment fails with

> force-app\main\default\classes\RestClientTest.cls  Method is not visible: void RestClient.()

but it really works fine in sandbox
when i try to deploy target class with

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass:RestClient -l RunSpecifiedTests -r RestClientTest
```

i always get

> Deploy ID: 0AfSc0000001d0vKAA
> DEPLOY PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 1/1 Components

=== Test Results Summary

Passing: 0
Failing: 0
Total: 0
Time: 0
Error (1): Deploy failed.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Compile All Classes feature mentioned in [Manage Apex Classes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_manage_packages.htm&type=5). You'll find this in Setup > Custom Code > Apex Classes. The most likely scenario is that there is another class that needs access to the constructor in order to compile, and Sandbox/Developer/Scratch Orgs do not perform a full compile to make deployments quicker. You may also want to pull down all of your production org's code and try deploying to the Sandbox. This way, you'll know about any other compile errors that may be lurking.